# Let $T_1,...,T_n, T \in V^{*}$. If $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} T_i ^{-1}(0) \subset T^{-1}(0)$, then T is a linear combination of $T_1,...,T_n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What I did:

Put $F:V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}^n, F(x)=(T_1(x),...,T_n(x))$ linear transformation, but $F^{-1}(0) \subset \bigcap_{i=1}^{n} T_i ^{-1}(0) \subset T^{-1}(0)$,besides, as $T_i^{-1}(0)$ is a hyperplane, there is $v_i \in V$, $V = T_i ^{-1}(0) \oplus [v_i]$

How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not assuming $V$ is finite-dimensional (there might be a simple proof in that case). I'll proceed via induction over $n$.

- $n=1$: if $T_1=0$ and $\ker T_1\subset \ker T$, then $T=0$. If $T_1\neq 0$, there is some $x_1$ such that $T_1x_1\neq 0$. Now note that $\displaystyle \forall x, x-\frac{T_1x}{T_1x_1}x_1\in \ker T_1$. Therefore, $\displaystyle T=\frac{Tx_1}{T_1x_1}T_1$
- suppose the claim holds for $n-1$ functionals, and consider $T_1,...,T_n, T \in V^{*}$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \ker T_i \subset \ker T$.

WLOG $T_1,\ldots, T_n$ is linearly independent. In that case, there exists (I leave the proof to you) $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ such that $\forall i, x_i \in \left(\bigcap_{j\neq i}\ker T_j\right)\setminus \ker T_i$.

Then $\displaystyle \forall x, x-\sum_{i} \frac{T_ix}{T_ix_i}x_i \in\bigcap_{i=1}^{n} \ker T_i$, which proves the claim.